Subject-verb agreement for "Most X and Y" subject
Would "is" or "are" be more correct in this sentence?

Most acute pharyngitis and laryngitis is/are caused by viral or, more rarely, bacterial infection.

I'm not sure if the verb should agree with "most" or with "pharyngitis and laryngitis."
Another sentence I'm having trouble with is this one:

Expert evaluation and diagnosis that ultimately directly or indirectly leads to therapeutic intervention is the task of the contemporary otolaryngologist.

Because the subject includes "evaluation and diagnosis," should the verbs be plural? i.e.

Expert evaluation and diagnosis that ultimately directly or indirectly lead to therapeutic intervention are the tasks of the contemporary otolaryngologist.


Where are these quotes from? The first at least is badly written.

Two subjects uses are.

In English, with compound nouns joined by "and", the general principle that if the two things form a unit, then they are considered as singular, but if they are two separate things they are plural. See this question and this question among many others, for different cases when this principle applies.
With "most X and Y" where X and Y are uncountable nouns, there are cases where it's treated as singular and cases where it's treated as plural. However it's not always obvious which is which, and such cases require some thought.
Does "most acute pharyngitis and laryngitis" refer to two separate types of disease, or a common phenomenon with a shared cause, maybe where they both infect the same person? If they are separate, use plural; if closely linked, use singular. In practice, it's often not clear-cut, and there are cases where either would do.
Some examples follow.
With "are":

The main reason for this is that most wheat grain and flour produced are not connected to specific assets and are traded mostly as commodities (Diffusion of circular economy practices in the UK wheat food supply chain, Northampton University)


Most violence and abuse are perpetrated by men, as illustrated by Australian data on violence overall (Queensland University of Technology)


Most oil and gas are stored in the zone where the formation temperature is 60–120 °C (Theoretical Progress and Key Technologies of Onshore Ultra-Deep Oil/Gas Exploration Elsevier Engineering)


North China, where almost half China's population lives and most wheat and corn are grown, is facing serious water crisis. (Institute of Atmospheric Physics, Beijing)

Some with "is":

Most violence and abuse is never reported. (Plan International)


While most violence and abuse is inflicted by men on women and girls, men can also be victims. (South Ayrshire Council, UK)


While almost all coal forms on land from terrestrial vegetation, most oil and gas is derived primarily from marine micro-organisms that accumulate within sea-floor sediments. Open Text BC


Most oil and gas is produced from porous underground or subsea reservoirs discovered by seismic surveys. (University of Edinburgh/NERC)


Some excellent analysis and examples. / There's an even trickier underlying complication with OP's first example. 'Most oil and gas' is simply short for 'most oil and most gas', but  'most acute pharyngitis and laryngitis' is arguably notionally short for 'most cases of acute pharyngitis and most cases of acute laryngitis'.
